# Groups $G$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, axiom-of-choice, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Inn{Inn}$First I hope my question belongs here, please let me know if it doesn't.

It isn't too hard to show there is no groups $G$ such that $\Aut(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p \geq 3$ prime. My question is: what happens when $p = 2$ ?

First, using the fact that if $\Inn(G)$ is finite and cyclic then $G$ is abelian, we get that $G$ is abelian and $\Inn(G)=\{\mathrm{Id}\}$.

Assuming $G$ is finitely generated, we can write $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n \times \mathbb{Z}/p_1\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/p_k\mathbb{Z}$.
Then, if $n \geq 2$, we get at least $4$ automorphisms.
If any $p_i$ is distinct of $2,3,4,6$, we would have $$2 < \varphi(n) =|\Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z})| = |(\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z})^\times|  \leq |\Aut(G)|.$$
If we have any factor of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2, (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^2,(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^2, (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})^2$, then we can exhibit $3$ atleast automorphisms.
After checking the remaining products by hand, we get that the followings satisfy $\Aut(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$:
$$\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$

We can also prove the second automorphism must be $x \mapsto -x$, assuming AoC:
If $x = -x$, then $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
When $\dim(G) = 0,1$, there is no nontrivial automorphism, as for when $\dim(G) > 2$, permutations of elements of a basis gives atleast $\dim(G)! > 2$ automorphisms.
When $\dim(G) = 2$, we can simply exhibit $3$ automorphisms.

Without any form of choice this doesn't hold though, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/axiom-of-choice-and-automorphisms-of-vector-spaces/) by Asaf Karagila, leading me to the question: does the statement $\Aut(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ iff $G$ is one of the finitely generated groups I gave above, depend on choice somehow ?

Comment: The automorphism group of $\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ is not cyclic of order $2$. Indeed, $w\mapsto -w$ is an automorphism of order $2$, and $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+\pi(x))$ is another one, where $\pi$ is the projection modulo 2. Same remark for $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: I think a more accurate title would be "Under ZF, finitely generated groups such that.."

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit to remove them. As for the title, I'm precisely asking what happens when the group isn't finitely generated anymore, so I don't understand the proposed edit.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Shika!

Comment: @Shika-Blyat indeed I was confused by your formulation. Is it a question about choice or not (I initially understood you were asking about f.g. abelian groups under ZF)? Maybe it would be useful to expand Karagila's assertion. Also see https://mathoverflow.net/a/198339/14094 which provides an infinitely generated abelian group with automorphism group of order 2.

Comment: My question is kind of vague, I'm wondering what can we say about a group $G$ satisfying $Aut(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
In particular, because the same question with $Aut(G) \simeq 0$ depends on choice, I was wondering if here too, we needed choice to get a group that isn't one of the finitely generated ones. Your link answers this question negatively (so thanks !).

Comment: I'm still confused about the question here - doesn't the answer by Asaf linked in the OP already answer the question negatively (by taking $\mathbb F=\mathbb F_3$)?

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, yes, that does work I think ! I feel dumb for missing that, I had the answer right under my nose the whole time.

Comment: So one question remains (except if it's also answered in Asaf's post ':) ), can we, assuming choice holds, find another group than the finitely generated ones, satisfying $\mathrm{Aut}(G) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Well, the answer I posted only dealt with the choiceless case, so it's definitely not there. (Also, it's nice to see people read it, that answer became the basis for my masters thesis.)

Comment: I see. In that case it seems YCor's answer is the most relevant one - for infinitely generated groups, counterexamples still exist, whether we accept choice or not.

Comment: As I said above, I don't see where the linked paper give an example of an infinitely generated group with endomorphism group being $\mathbb{Z}$ (I'm probably just missing it), could someone share the page number ?

Comment: See Lemma 2 on second to last page, specifically property (c) of the group.

Comment: If the answer I point out in a comment answers the question, shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate? Actually I would have voted so, but unfortunately I have this stupid "golden badge"  for the [tag:gr.group-theory] tag, which means it would be closed as duplicate based on my own vote, and I don't like this.

Comment: (I had all the answers I wanted, so I'm okay with closing it. I'd do it myself if I knew how to do it.)